# Binary tree in java with getters and setters

Tags: java, binary-tree

I'm trying to create binary tree by following example  1 where tree is made without getters and setters. I would like to create it with geeters and setters but I'm stuck on line with recursion. How can I call recursion function  with/inside setter? Here is the code..
p.s. Tree class [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Kqk9dGQj)

```
public class TreeF {

Tree root;

public void insert(int value) {

    if (root==null) {

    root = new Tree(value);
        return;
    }

     Tree current = root;

    if (value < current.getData() ) {

        if (current.getLeft()==null) {
            current.setLeft(new Tree (value));
        }else {
            // call insert method inside current.left object [currrent.left(insert(value))]
            current=current.getLeft();
            insert (value);
        }

    }
    else {
        if (current.getRight()==null) {
            current.setRight(new Tree (value));
        }else {
            current=current.getRight();
            insert (value);

        }
     }  
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `insert(value)` to `current.insert(value)`

To implement recursion, you need to change a parameter(or multiple) so you can go to the stopping condition after some recursive calls.

In your code, you called the method `insert` that was part of the same object. And not its left/right subtree. In other words, the recursion never ends, because you don't visit the child subtrees.

```
public class Tree {
private int data;
private Tree left;
private Tree right;

public Tree (int data) {
    this.data=data;
}

public int getData() {
    return data;
}
public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}
public Tree getLeft() {
    return left;
}
public void setLeft(Tree left) {
    this.left = left;
}
public Tree getRight() {
    return right;
}
public void setRight(Tree right) {
    this.right = right;
}

public void insert(int value) {
    if (value <  getData()) {
        if (getLeft() == null) {
            setLeft(new Tree(value));
        } else {
            getLeft().insert(value);
        }
    } else {
        if (getRight() == null) {
            setRight(new Tree(value));
        } else {
            getLeft().insert(value);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: when I change insert(value) to current.insert(value) I got message create method  insert (int) in type Tree.. I have paste my Tree class in pastebin

Comment: Then you dont need a new class for TreeF. I will update the answer

Comment: also paste the code in the question, not in pastebin

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `current` field or a `root`. Here's your `insert` method greatly simplified to demonstrate.

```
public class Tree {
    final int data;
    Tree left;
    Tree right;

    public Tree(int value) {
        data = value;
    }

    public void insert(int value) {
        if (value < data) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new Tree(value);
            } else {
                left.insert(value);
            }
        } else {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new Tree(value);
            } else {
                right.insert(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```